# Max Date Last Update Date SQL

Tags: sql

I am asking for help with this item. I am a novice to SQL and not very sure how to handle this problem I appreciate any help from the forum.

I have a table that is updated multiple times a day. I would like to create a view that only displays the last update that was made for a given day.

Here is a sample of the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSq4K.png)

This is the desired result of the SQL Query when the data set provided has been queries

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WV5q.png)

Answer (score -1):

As I understood you want to get the last record of every day.

Just group it by day

You will have to use EXTRACT to do it

Example: EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)

Then select the max time from the column where you have the time of the day. If you dont have the time in a different column you will also need to extract it.

```
SELECT MAX(TIME_COLUMN) FROM `TABLE_NAME`
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT MAX (your_date) AS "Max Date"
FROM your_table

Comment: Yes I could use max date which would also require a group by. If the values were different  then I would be grouping by a value when I only care about the records associated with the max date.